# How to edit System.IO.Ports in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi

Right so I have installed Mono on a Raspberry pi (Debian)
However I want to patch System.IO.Ports

http://antanas.veiverys.com/enabling-serialport-datareceived-event-in-mono/#more-96

This dude has found a workaround to make the Serial datareceived event fire in linux

I just don't know how to implement his idea?

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret that diff or how to rebuild mono after you modified the target file?

Comment: I am asking what I have to do to make his patch happen.. is there a file somewhere on my system called "system.io.ports" which I have to go into and change.. or do I have to somehow change the install file..

BUt I just installed it from "sudo apt-get install mono-complete" how would I edit that if I had to do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply the patch you will have to build mono from source, there is a [very thorough guide for that on github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README).

But before doing that i would:

1. Test that this isn't fixed in the newest mono version
2. Find out if there is a workaround that doesn't require changing mono source

Comment: Thanks a lot I will get on that now